# Is negative sum of logarithms of softmax functions convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am trying to prove that
$$f(\mathbf{x}) = -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln\left(\frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum_{j=i}^{n}e^{x_{j}}}\right) \quad \forall\;\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$$
is convex. I have already tried to show it via the definition of convex function, via monotonicity of the gradient and via Hessian matrix. None of the above methods allowed me to show that the function is convex. Is it really non-convex or I am missing something?

Comment: Welcome! Kindly add context to the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$
f(x) = \frac1n \sum_{i = 1}^n \ln\left( \sum_{j=i}^n e^{x_j - x_i} \right),$$
(why?). Can you finish from here?

Comment: I get what you have done. This definitely helped me to go further but I still was not able to prove the last step $\sum_{j=1}^{n}e^{\alpha{x_{j}} + (1-\alpha)y_{j}} \leq (\sum_{j=1}^{n}e^{x_{j}})^{\alpha}(\sum_{j=1}^{n}e^{y_{j}})^{1 - \alpha}$. I was using the definition of convexity to arrive to this. Intuitively this inequality seems correct but I can't find a way to show it rigorously.

Comment: If the inequality that I have come up with wrong, could you please provide full solution. I have been struggling with the problem for more than a week already. I think I might be blind for some small details that do not allow me to find a solution.

Comment: @mathhacker Try using the fact that the function above is a sum of log-sum-exp functions composed with linear transformations of your variable.

Comment: @mathhacker: A nice arguement is to use $e^{\alpha x + (1-\alpha)y} = e^{\alpha x} e^{(1-\alpha)y}$ and then apply Hölder's inequality for sums.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot

Comment: Turns out, for me the missing piece was Hölder's inequality.